# The value of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

The value of series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}$

I try to write some terms,but of no use. Is there any general method to approach such questions.

Thanks

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn).

Comment: This is one of the most asked questions about series: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series?sort=frequent&pageSize=50

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n x^n=x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n x^{n-1}=x \frac d {dx}\Big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n}\Big)$$

When you finish, replace $x$ by $\frac 12$.

## Happy New Year

Comment: @DunVatta. You are very welcome ! Cheers and remember the trick (you will need to use it a lot of time).

Answer (score 6):

Notice that
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}
= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n+1}{2^n}
= \frac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}
   + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n} + 1,
\end{align*}
thus $\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n} \right) = 2$.

Comment: why can we do this with an infinity sum, i this alowed? which rules did you used?

Comment: I just used linearity of the limit and index shifting, both of which are basic facts about convergent series.

Comment: often the binomial formulas are not basic facts for the students!

Comment: "Binomial"? What the...

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }nx^{n-1}=(\frac{1}{1-x})'$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }nx^{n}=x(\frac{1}{1-x})'$$
plug $x=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

prove by induction that $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{2^i}=-2\, \left( 1/2 \right) ^{n+1} \left( n+1 \right) -2\, \left( 1/2
 \right) ^{n+1}+2
$$ and then calculate the limit.

Comment: No: the complete series is easier.

Comment: yes, this is one way to find the sum for $n$ tends to infinity. Your statement is wrong this is the partial sum and with that we can prove if  the infinity sum exists

Comment: have a short look in a book for analysis

Comment: both authors haven't anythink said if such operations with an infinity sum are allowed this gives $-1$ and not for me

Comment: You can simplify it to $-2^{-n}(n+2)+2$.

Comment: the OP must also do something thank you for your hint the searched limit is in this form better to find

Comment: How easy is it to build it without a CAS ?